# Trying sub-setting dataframe in R

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to sub set dataframe by comparing values in two column. I am using below line

```
open <- open[open$AssignedGroup==open$Assigned.Group, ]
```

It was working fine, but it didn't work when some values in columns have more character
For example ,
I got below value in both column for same rows, but above script unable to subset dataframe.
ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2

Can anyone please help me to know what is the issue here?

Inserting first 10 rows for reference

```
Num AssignedGroup   Priority    Assigned.Group
1   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  Medium  ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
1   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  Medium  Group 1
1   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  Medium  Group 2
2   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  High    ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
2   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  High    Group 1
2   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  High    Group 2
3   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  Low ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
3   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  Low Group 1
3   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  Low Group 2
4   ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2  Low ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
```

I have inserted structure of dataframe for reference

```
'data.frame':   82710 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Num           : chr  "INC0615378" "INC0615378" "INC0615378" "INC0615495" ...
 $ AssignedGroup : chr  "ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2" "ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2" "ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2" "ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2" ...
 $ Priority      : chr  "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" ...
 $ Assigned.Group: chr  "ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2" "GROUP 1" "Group 2" "ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2" ...
```

Comment: please add a reproducible dataset using `deput(head(YourDataSet,10))`

Comment: try this open <- open[which(open$AssignedGroup %like% open$Assigned.Group), ]

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara, I have inserted first 10 rows of dataframe for reference. I wanted to exclude rows in which "AssignedGroup" and "Assigned.Group" doesn't have same values

Comment: @shirin, I tried your suggestion got below warning and it return 0 rows in dataframe "Warning message:
In grepl(pattern, vector) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: i asked you to add a `dput` result. Now, i need to have `str(dt)` as well

Comment: @user3734568 switch the two columns and try again so use:open <- open[which(open$Assigned.Group %like% open$AssignedGroup), ] the warning message tells you that only ABC is used to match the two instead of ABC DE Demo which I'm not sure if it's fine with you or not. to better help you, it is useful to know unique(open$AssignedGroup) (if not too many...)

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara, inserted structure of dataframe for reference. script works when character length is short but for lengthy it is not working

Comment: @shirin, Tried switching columns it is not working

Comment: @user3734568 you may have overwritten your original dataset already so try reading it in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
 Num<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4)
 AssignedGroup<-rep("ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2",10)
 Assigned.Group<-c("ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2","Group 1",
 "Group 2","ABC DE    Demo Integration E2E test 2","Group 1",
 "Group 2","ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2","Group 1",
 "Group 2","ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2")
 Priority<-c(rep("Medium",3),rep("High",3),rep("Low",4))
 df<- as.data.frame(cbind(Num,AssignedGroup,Priority,Assigned.Group))
 library(data.table)
 dfSubset<-df[which(df$Assigned.Group %like% df$AssignedGroup), ]
 dfSubset
#   Num           AssignedGroup             Priority              Assigned.Group
 #1    1 ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2   Medium ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
 #4    2 ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2     High ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
 #7    3 ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2      Low ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
 #10   4 ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2      Low ABC DE Demo Integration E2E test 2
```

Comment: I tried above it worked for me as well, actually earlier it was working well , now when there is huge data it is failed, don't understanding issue

Comment: my bad I found issue there is extra space in Assigned.Group column between "Demo" "Integration", in actual dataframe that's why it is not sub setting, really sorry for trouble

Comment: @user3734568 great can you please flag this as the correct answer then thanks